# Installed Jboss 7 to Centos 6.4 when starting jboss all websites became inaccessible.

Tags: php, jboss, vps

I have a `VPS` at bluehost.com and I have a few websites in public_html. I installed jdk 7 and jboss 7 to my server.

I then started the jboss server like this,

```
./standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0&
```

Then checked my sites made in php typical wordpress sites and they are all displaying

`this webpage is not available.`

So then I stopped the jboss server like this,

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown
```

But the web pages still display

`this webpage is not available.`

At that point I rebooted the server and still no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.